# PDO connection statement works on test server but not live

Tags: php, pdo

I have a pdo script that is a basic login script. It works just fine on my test server. But on my live server won't function. I am getting a PDO error:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected' in /nas/content/live/inboundpro/leadportal/index.php:40\nStack trace:\n#0 /nas/content/live/inboundpro/leadportal/index.php(40): PDOStatement->execute()\n#1 {main}\n thrown in /nas/content/live/inboundpro/leadportal/index.php on line 40, referer: http://www.inboundprospect.com/leadportal/

```
     <?php
    session_start();

    //DB configuration Constants
    define('_HOST_NAME_', '162.242.221.151;3306');
    define('_USER_NAME_', '*******');
    define('_DB_PASSWORD', '*******');
    define('_DATABASE_NAME_', '*******');

    //PDO Database Connection
    try {
        $databaseConnection = new PDO('mysql:host='._HOST_NAME_.';dbname='._DATABASE_NAME_, _USER_NAME_, _DB_PASSWORD);
        $databaseConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $errMsg = '';
        //username and password sent from Form
        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);

        if($username == '')
            $errMsg .= 'You must enter your Username<br>';

        if($password == '')
            $errMsg .= 'You must enter your Password<br>';


        if($errMsg == ''){
            $records = $databaseConnection->prepare('SELECT id,username,password,hash FROM tbl_users WHERE username = :username');
            $records->bindParam(':username', $username);
            $records->execute();
            $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($password, $results['hash'])){
                $_SESSION['username'] = $results['username'];
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                header('location:dashboard.php');
                exit;
            }else{
                $errMsg .= 'Username and Password are not found<br>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Login Page PHP Script</title>
<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="front">
        <div class="center">

            <div class="LoginPortal">
                <?php
                    if(isset($errMsg)){
                        echo '<div style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:12px;background-color:white;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">'.$errMsg.'</div>';
                    }
                ?>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="formTop"><img src="images/IP_Logo_SOLO.png"></div>

                    <div class="Formcenter">
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="box" placeholder="USERNAME"/>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="box" placeholder="PASSWORD"/><br />
                    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit" class='submit'/>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div><!-- close center -->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What did i miss?

Comment: Does that database exist on your live server? Do you see anything printed with "Error: " before your PDO error? View the source of the page in your browser if you have to.

Comment: If your connection fails, your script will continue running and try to use the failed database connection further down. You should probably handle the error and just show an error (and log it) if that happens. (And only create the connection if you need to use it. Now it creates the connection on every call, regardless if you actually use it or not).

Comment: The strange part about all of this is that this all works fine on my personal server. the only thing i should have to change out is the login credentials which i did but its still a no go. i literally copied the database tables over to the new DB

Comment: Take the `;3306` out of your host name. It's the default port, so it's not needed. If you do need to specify it, you have to specify the what it is: `;port=3306`

Comment: Also, if the database resides on the same server as the web host, try using `localhost` instead of the IP. It can change how mysql sees your connection (user@localhost vs user@i.p.address